# Sorted/unique list of object instances from a larger list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of object instances that I want to sort/uniqueify into a new list.  Each object implements a variety of properties, but the three properties of importance are `a`, `b`, and `c`.  All three properties return an integer value, with `a` and `b` sorted low-to-high and `c` sorted high-to-low.

Example list:

```
>>> x
>>> [<Foo object at 0x2b371b90>, <Foo object at 0x2b371f38>, <Foo object at 0x2b3719e0>, <Foo object at 0x2b376320>, <Foo object at 0x2b3765f0>]
```

If I loop and printed the value of `a`, `b`, and `c` in a tuple for each object, they would look like this:

```
>>> for o in x:
...    print (o.a, o.b, o.c)
...
(2, 78342112, 9)
(2, 78342117, 3)
(2, 78342112, 10)
(2, 78342112, 8)
(2, 78342117, 4)
```

I've figured out how to sort the list by `a`/`b` being low-to-high and `c` being high-to-low by defining a `key()` function in the object's class:

```
def key(self):
    return (self.a, self.b, -self.c)
```

And passing that to `sorted()`:

```
x2 = sorted(x, key=lambda x:x.key())
>>> for o in x2:
...    print (o.a, o.b, o.c)
...
(2, 78342112, 10)
(2, 78342112, 9)
(2, 78342112, 8)
(2, 78342117, 4)
(2, 78342117, 3)
```

For these specific objects, uniqueness between instances depends on if `a` and `b` are the same values between two instances.  If they are different, then `c` is never considered, else, we favor the largest value of `c`.  What I'd like to do is generate a new list from either `x` or `x2` in my examples above that only contains one instance for each case when `a` and `b` are the same, and retain the one whose `c` value is largest.  The new list, `x3`, would look like this:

```
>>> x3 = <magic sorting/unique function called here>
>>> for o in x3:
...    print (o.a, o.b, o.c)
...
(2, 78342112, 10)
(2, 78342117, 4)
```

I think I can do this using `reduce()` and a custom function, but the algorithm/logic to do so simply stumps me at the moment.

Ideas?

Comment: Nicer to just use the unbound function `key=ClassName.key`

Comment: @gnibbler: Was not aware of that approach.  A lot of examples that I see just use a `lambda` and test some property from an object.  Is there any background on how that works?

Comment: it's just a neater way to call your `key` function. Remember that `Foo.key(foo)` is the same as calling `foo.key()`. Since foo is passed the the key function, you can leave the lambda out by using the unbound method instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

x3 = [next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(x2, lambda x:(x.a, x.b))]
```

This picks the first element of each group with the same key.

Comment: I know I tagged this python-2.7, but I'm testing inside a Python 2.4 interpreter at the moment, which lacks the `next()` method.  Know of an implementation of `next()` for 2.4?

Comment: `next(g)` translates to `g.next()` if you don't have the `next` function.

Comment: @NPE: Thanks for the answer.  I am going to have to study `itertools` a bit more and see what else in that module I can leverage.